# Trigonometric calculation help

Tags: trigonometry

How do I go about solving:

1.) cos 18$^\circ$ $\cdot$ (tg 36$^\circ$ + ctg 36$^\circ$)

2.) cos 10$^\circ$ + $cos^2  20$$^\circ$ + 4 cos 15$^\circ$ cos 75$^\circ$ + $cos^2 70$$^\circ$ + cos 170$^\circ$

I do not know what identities to use or what is the technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$.$$\cos(18^{\circ})\left( \tan (36^{\circ}) +\cot (36^{\circ})  \right) =\cos (18^{\circ}) \left( \frac { \sin (36^{\circ})  }{ \cos (36^{\circ})  } +\frac { \cos (36^{\circ}) }{ \sin (36^{\circ})  }  \right) =$$ $$=\cos (18^{\circ}) \left( \frac { \sin ^{ 2 }(36^{\circ}) +\cos ^{ 2 }(36^{\circ})  }{ \sin (36^{\circ}) \cos (36^{\circ})  }  \right) =\cos { (18^{\circ})\left( \frac { 2 }{ 2\sin (36^{\circ}) \cos (36^{\circ})  }  \right)  } =$$ $$ \\ =\cos (18^{\circ})\frac { 2 }{ \sin (72^{\circ})  } =\cos { 18 } \frac { 2 }{ \sin { \left( (90^{\circ}-72^{\circ} \right)  }  } =2$$

$2.$ Since $\cos(70^{\circ}) =\sin (20^{\circ}) ,\cos (170^{\circ}) =-\cos (10^{\circ})  ,\cos { (75^{\circ})=\sin (15^{\circ})  } \\ $ we have  $$\cos (10^{\circ}) +\cos ^{ 2 }(20^{\circ}) +4\cos (15^{\circ}) \cos (75^{\circ}) +\cos ^{ 2 }(70^{\circ}) +\cos (170^{\circ}) =\\ =\cos { (10^{\circ})+\cos ^{ 2 }{ (20^{\circ})+4\cos { (15^{\circ})\sin { (75^{\circ})+\sin ^{ 2 }(20^{\circ}) -\cos (10^{\circ}) = }  }  }  } \\ =1+2\sin (30^{\circ}) =2$$

Comment: Thank you! It was so easy.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $1)$: $\cos (36^{\circ}) = \sin ( 54^{\circ})\implies 1-2\sin^2(18^{\circ}) = 3\sin (18^{\circ}) - 4\sin^3 (18^{\circ})$. You can solve for $\sin (18^{\circ})$, and then $\cos(18^{\circ})$,and $\tan(18^{\circ})$. Observe $(\sin(18^{\circ})-1)$ is a factor.

$2)$: $\cos(10^{\circ}) + \cos (170^{\circ}) = 0, \cos^2 (20^{\circ})+ \cos^2(70^{\circ}) = 1, 2\cos(15^{\circ})\cos (75^{\circ})= \cos(90^{\circ})+\cos(60^{\circ})= \dfrac{1}{2}$